# Spark: How RDD.map/mapToPair work with Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, tuples, rdd, keyvaluepair

I have some pairs cw (Integer i, String word) with *i* number of occurences of *word* in a text file.

I would like to simply have for each pair a new pair c1 (Integer i, 1) with 1 fixed number.

It seems to be really trivial but I haven't understood how map/mapToPair functions actually work.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> c1 = cw.map(??? -> new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(??, 1));
```

I am working using Java-8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have below JavaPairRDD.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> cw = ...;
```

Now you want to create below JavaPairRDD where second value is 1.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> c1;
```

In order to get this, first you have to extract JavaRDD from `cw` JavaPairRDD and for this you will have to call `map` function like below. We will extract first value from pair.

```
JavaRDD<Integer> cw1 = cw.map(tuple -> tuple._1());
```

Now you will create new JavaPairRDD from JavaRDD using `mapToPair` function like below.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> c1 = cw1.mapToPair(i -> new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(i, 1));
```

In single line you can write it like

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> c1 = cw.map(tuple -> tuple._1()).mapToPair(i -> new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(i, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can try:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> tuples = filtered.mapToPair(
                                            f -> new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(
                                                       Integer.parseInt(f[0]), 
                                                       Integer.parseInt(f[1])
                                       ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply ... `cw.mapValues(v -> 1);`

From the api docs for [JavaPairRDD.mapValues()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) ...

> Pass each value in the key-value pair RDD through a map function
>   without changing the keys; this also retains the original RDD's
>   partitioning.

Comment: Why the mark down? This is a much cleaner solution that answers the question  ... _I would like to simply have for each pair a new pair c1 (Integer i, 1) with 1 fixed number_